# creating multiple web page in rails 3 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am fairly new to Ruby and Rails. I am using rails 3. I am creating a project where people can login and post jobs and people can search jobs etc. I have created my users model and jobs model and everything is working just fine. I have started creating the home page layout and have added links to the other pages post work, find work, contact, about. I have a few questions hopefully someone can help please.

1. When I get into the rails server and check out the project and my home page it shows the login set up from the users model and it also shows the jobs model where someone can post a job. I am trying to figure out how I can make it so the jobs do not get posted on the home page but the find work page and people can search from that page? Do I need to link the jobs model to the find work page something like that?
2. How do I create the web pages for these other links i have established. I can not figure out how to build the page layout for the post work link i have or the other links I have for people to view the page layout. Any help is appreciated? Thanks again!

Comment: I have used devise to set up my users model and also have set up twitter-bootstrap for the layout part if that helps any.

Comment: You may want to run through a tutorial on Rails.  This one seems complete and relevant to what you're trying to accomplish - http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app. This should help you get started, and allow you to ask more specific questions if you run into problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you ask is mostly the basics of Rails. You can render jobs or any other model in any view you want, you just need to "send" these jobs to the views from you controller.

**1.- Configure routes:**

```
#config/routes.rb
get "/jobs" match 'jobs#index' # i.e 'controller#action'
```

**2.- Configure model controller:**

```
#app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @jobs = Jobs.last(10)
    render 'index'
  end
end
```

**3.- Configure view:**

```
#app/views/jobs/index.html.erb
<% @jobs.each do |job| "do something with each #{job}" end %>
```

This is just a birds sight overview you should check some Rails tutorials.

About generating pages for content that isn't in the db...

I had this issue once and solved it like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
get "/:view" match 'home#views' # rails g controller home

#app/controllers/views_controller.rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def views
    render params[:view]
  end
end
```

Now generate a view for each new page, lets say "About", under `/app/views/home` and you can access each of them via `/view_name`.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the information. I will check it out tonight and see what I can come up with. Appreciate any help is always good specially with being new still. I have read alot of tutorial and classes regarding rails and it has help but you can only read so much before you just have to dig in and get dirty.